# Tab keyascii in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

for example I've 3 elements in my HTML code for text input.

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" />
<input type="text" name="txt2" />
<input type="text" name="txt3" />
```

At first load, I set by js to focus in **txt1**.
My question is, How I can manipulate keyascii when I pressing **tab** from **txt1** to **txt3** ?

The fact, I've added some js code with jquery to do that, but doesn't work! It's always focused to **txt2**. This is my js code:

```
$('input[name="txt1"]').keyup(function(e){
        if((e.keyWhich || e.keyCode) == 9){
            $('input[name="txt3"]').focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should make the magic. Though you could use also `tabindex` attribute for your `input`s.

Comment: @teemu where I should place that one?

Comment: isn't it `e.which` rather than `e.keyWhich` ?

Comment: @mohkhan `e.keyWhich` worked

Comment: @AldiUnanto I suppose `e.keyWhich` is not working, rather the browser you're testing with, has just implemented `e.keyCode`. Btw, the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#tabindex)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for `keydown` and use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour.
The default behaviour for pressing `tab` is executed before the `keyup` event is being fired. That's why you have to use `keydown` instead.

```
$('input[name="txt1"]').keydown(function(e){
    if((e.keyWhich || e.keyCode) == 9){            
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="txt3"]').focus();
    }
});
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2nkM/1/)

Comment: Have you found the right answer brother? I can't open the fiddle caused anything wrong with my connection

Comment: Yes, I moved the `preventDefault()` in the conditional statement, so it's only executed for the tab key

Comment: I've do that before, and It's only focussing to **txt2**

Comment: My fiddle works in both firefox and chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32729/discussion-between-kilian-stinson-and-aldi-unanto)

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for keydown instead and be using e.preventDefault()

Example:

```
$('input[name="txt1"]').keydown(function(e){
    if((e.keyWhich || e.keyCode) == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="txt3"]').focus();
    }
});
```

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNzWd/2/)

[Documentation of preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Sorry about that. Total brainfart of me. The preventDefault should have been wrapped in your conditional that checked for tab key. Updated.